# "Maximum call stack size" Error When Adding Data to Chartjs Using Props With Fetch (Vue/Chartjs)

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use a method to fetch data from a json file and add it to my chart.js chart. I keep getting a "Maximum call stack size exceeded", this is specifically caused by the `this.chartData.push(el.value);` line, I've tried changing naming around to no success as well as using `this.$data.chartData`.

I am using vue3, chart.js v3 and j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs

here is a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-dijkstra-ufh75) of the code with the error.

> Child (chart) component

```js
<template>
  <div class="card card-body bg-dark">
    <div class="col" id="chart">
      <vue3-chart-js
        ref="chartRef"
        :id="sampleChart.id"
        :type="sampleChart.type"
        :data="sampleChart.data"
        :options="sampleChart.options"
      ></vue3-chart-js>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Vue3ChartJs from "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs"
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';

var chartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  responsive: true,
  animation: {
    duration: 500
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      yAlign: "bottom",
    },
  },
  interaction: {
    mode: "index",
    intersect: false,
    axis: "x",
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "time",
      time: {
        unit: "minute"
      }
    },
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      pointRadius: 5.0,
    },
  },
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 20,
      left: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 10,
    },
  },
}

export default {
  name: "Chart",
  components: {
    Vue3ChartJs,
  },
  props: {
    chartData: Array,
    chartLabels: Array
  },
  setup(props) {
    const chartRef = ref(null)
    console.log("area chart data", props.chartData)

    const chartDetails = {
      labels: props.chartLabels,
      fill: true,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "",
          data: props.chartData,
          borderColor: "rgb(24, 144, 255)",
          tension: 0.1,
          fill: true,
        },
      ],
    }
    const sampleChart = {
      id: "line",
      type: "line",
      data: chartDetails,
      options: chartOptions,
    }

    return {
      sampleChart,
      chartRef
    }
  },
  watch: {
    chartLabels: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.chartRef.update(250)
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
#chart {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

> Parent component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <SampleChart :chart-data="chartData" :chart-labels="chartLabels" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SampleChart from "./SampleChart.vue";

export default {
  components: { SampleChart },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: [],
      chartLabels: [],
    };
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    this.getTimelineData();
  },
  methods: {
    getTimelineData: function () {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/sample.json")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.data.forEach((el) => {
            this.chartData.push(el.value);
            this.chartLabels.push(el.timestamp);
          });
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

> Package.json dependencies

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.3.2",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.1.5"
  }
```

> The Error Message

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.get (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:231)
    at toRaw (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:743)
    at Proxy.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:223)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.segment.js?dd3d:1531)
    at Proxy.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:223)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.segment.js?dd3d:1531)
    at Proxy.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:223)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.segment.js?dd3d:1531)
    at Proxy.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:223)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.segment.js?dd3d:1531)
```

> Sample method without fetch that worked fine

```js
    getTestData: function () {
      var labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
      var values = [10, 25, 39, 55, 90, 202, 304, 202, 105, 33, 44, 95, 20, 39, 90];
      labels.forEach((el) => {
        this.chartLabels.push(el);
      });
      values.forEach((el) => {
        this.chartData.push(el);
      });
    },
```

> Json data sample

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1627382793000,
      "value": 121
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1627383698000,
      "value": 203
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1627387917000,
      "value": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Hossem's answer will work for the first render, the chart still wont be updated when you add new data.

Oddly enough, downgrading Vue one version from 3.1.5 to 3.1.4 ended up resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it's work when adding a simple v-if with a `ready` property that we turn it true when we finish the foreach of pushing data,

the problem is with your `SampleChart.vue` componenent , you make chart data inside the setup , so when data changed sampleChart will not be changed in any case , it's already calculated.
you can learn more about [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html), [ref/reactive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thanks! It works, I was confused because the getTestData() worked fine and was able to change the data, thought it had to do with the fetch for some reason.